# Is there any way to find out Xpath of an element in ubuntu by usung appium?

Tags: python, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator

i do not have access to mac to run the appium inspector, i tried using UI automate viewer , but the element could not be located as it did not have an id, is there any way to find and tap on element with no resource-id,text value ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, please use appium locator to find the xpath of the highlighted button but UI automation viewer doesn't give you xpath.

Comment: How to open appium locator on Ubuntu?